# How has the MNIST data set be preprocessed in the MNIST tutorials?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was going through [the MNIST tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) and was wondering, how the data set was preprocessed. In particular, I thought that images usually have integer values to express the intensity of a pixel. For example in the range 0 to 255 was what I thought. However, when I inspected one of the pixel values I got float values, something different from what I expected. Check the end of the vector:

0.80784321,  0.96470594,  0.6156863 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01568628,  0.45882356,  0.27058825,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ])

To check if maybe is was normalized such that each vector was unit norm I did:

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
LA.norm(X_train[0,:])
10.20854430695328
```

but as can be seen, norm of the vector is larger than 1.

Therefore I thought that maybe they were not scaled as I thought and maybe they were scaled using statistics normalization as in `Z = X - mu/ std`. To check that hypothesis I went through [the scipy tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) to scale images. For this I checked the mean of the data and the standard deviation using the commands:

```
X_train.mean(axis=0)
```

and

```
X_train.std(axis=0)
```

When I did that, what I got were vectors that were not standardized, i.e. they did not have mean 0 nor standard dev 1. The mean one said:

```
     1.48377906e-04,   3.16577558e-04,   4.71443878e-04,
     7.53226424e-04,   1.28991095e-03,   1.64713022e-03,
     1.94303042e-03,   2.20263827e-03,   2.67707680e-03,
     2.33504470e-03,   1.88178264e-03,   1.35629241e-03,
     7.74688105e-04,   3.29839591e-04,   1.72834236e-04,
     6.32442098e-05,   5.16221064e-05,   8.55615031e-06,
     0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
     0.00000000e+00])
```

and the std one said:

```
     9.73316794e-03,   1.48564994e-02,   1.79109386e-02,
     2.39294057e-02,   2.96610268e-02,   3.52616872e-02,
     3.74964883e-02,   3.94864147e-02,   4.46018863e-02,
     4.14498684e-02,   3.67526868e-02,   3.19768868e-02,
     2.35492900e-02,   1.51583259e-02,   1.10631365e-02,
     6.06049238e-03,   6.49226612e-03,   1.41963927e-03,
     0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
     0.00000000e+00])
```

therefore, I wanted to know, how is the MNIST data set preprocessed in the tensorflow tutorials since I exhausted all the possibilities I had.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in a vector, let's call it mnist, you can check what is the maximum value.

```
numpy.amax(mnist)
```

Should yield 1, thus means all values in the vector are between 0 and 1, ergo standardized.